# Firebase Error: Object 'XXX/XXX/XXX.jpg' does not exist when uploading unique storage folders based on user UID

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am trying to create unique storage folders based on a user's UID and then store all of the user's uploaded photos into that newly created folder onto Firebase using React.

Here is how I am uploading onto the Firebase storage:

In `Firebase.js`

```
constructor(){
   app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   this.auth = app.auth();
   this.db = app.database();
   this.storage = app.storage();
   this.storageRef = app.storage().ref('avatars');
}


updateAvatar = (avatar) => this.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({photoURL:avatar});

updateAvatarDb = (uid, avatar) => this.db.ref(`profiles/${uid}`).update({photoUrl: avatar});

currentUser = () => this.auth.currentUser;

fileRef = (filename, uid) => this.storageRef.child(`${uid}/${filename}`);
```

In `UploadPhoto.js`

```
    componentDidUpdate(){
        const user = this.props.firebase.currentUser();
        this.props.firebase.updateAvatar(this.state.avatarURL);
        this.props.firebase.updateAvatarDb(user.uid, this.state.avatarURL);
    }

    handleUploadSuccess = filename => {

        const user = this.props.firebase.currentUser();
        const img = this.props.firebase.fileRef(filename, user.uid);
        img.getDownloadURL()
            .then(url =>  this.setState({ avatarURL: url }));
      };


    render() {
        const {avatarURL, error} = this.state;
        const isInvalid = avatarURL === '';

        return(
            <form className = "ui form" onSubmit = {this.onSubmit}>
                <Segment stacked>
                    <FileUploader
                        accept="image/*"
                        name="avatar"
                        storageRef={this.props.firebase.storageRef}
                        onUploadStart={this.handleUploadStart}
                        onUploadError={this.handleUploadError}
                        onUploadSuccess={this.handleUploadSuccess}
                        onProgress={this.handleProgress}
                    />
...
```

When I do this, I get error code 404 which says:
`Object 'photos/HBLLFuaiQuQuNTWrgqH3kPEBq7G3/image.jpg' does not exist.`

I've tried manually inserting folder `photos/HBLLFuaiQuQuNTWrgqH3kPEBq7G3` using the Firebase Storage console and then running the code but I get the same message.

However, when I get rid of the UID so I load to path `photos/image.jpg`, then I have no problem uploading to the Firebase storage and no longer get the error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is the line of code that actually performs the upload?  How does it relate to `handleUploadSuccess`?  Are you certain that `handleUploadSuccess` runs only after the upload is fully complete?

Comment: Hi Doug, sorry I should've added more code and specified that I was using ```react-firebase-file-uploader```, I've edited the original post to include more code. I realize now that my issue was that I was not passing the UID into the ```storageRef``` argument. Thank you!

Comment: So there's no problem here now?

Comment: Correct, no problem here now!